# Troubles with numpy array operations

Tags: python, numpy

I'm quite new to numpy's vectorized operations world,

I have a simple array of the type:

```
X = np.full((4,5),[2,2,2,2,2])
>>> array([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
          [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
          [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
          [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

I'm trying to apply the numpy logarithm to odd indexed columns simply doing:

```
X[:,1::2] = np.log(X[:,1::2])
```

but the output is an unexpected:

```
array([[2, 0, 2, 0, 2],
       [2, 0, 2, 0, 2],
       [2, 0, 2, 0, 2],
       [2, 0, 2, 0, 2]])
```

Is there any issue? Really hanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with data types - you implicitly initialise X as integers. To fix you can set `dtype` in `np.full`:

`X = np.full((4,5),[2,2,2,2,2], dtype=float)`

Answer (score 0):

The value of `log(2)` is `0.69..`. Since, no datatype was given while making the numpy array, program treated `X` as numpy array with **`int`** datatype.

So, it basically converted `0.69....` to `0`. So, thats why you got `0` instead of `0.69..`.
It will convert every `float` datatype to `int`.

If you want `float` datatype, specify the datatype as `float`

```
X = np.full((4,5),[2,2,2,2,2], dtype=float)
```